# How do I run another web site or web service side by side with Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, iis

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to run another web service on an IIS 6 server which is also running Sharepoint 2003.  I'm pretty sure this is an issue with sharepoint taking over IIS configuration.  Is there a way to make a certain web service or web site be ignored by whatever Sharepoint is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the command line solution.

```
STSADM.EXE -o addpath -url http://localhost/<your web service/app> -type exclusion
```

Answer (score 1):

I depends on what you mean by side by side, if you are trying to make something inside the same URL path as sharepoint then the above answers about managed paths should do it for you, but there is also nothing stopping you from just creating another Web Site inside of IIS, sharepoint will only take over the requests coming to its specific web.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to go into the SharePoint admin console and explicitely allow that web application to run on on the same web site as SharePoint.

I believe it is under defined managed paths.

Central Administration > Application Management > Define Managed Paths

Answer (score 0):

Hasn't this change from 2003 to 2007? There's no longer an excluded paths option.